# Fetch & alternate element from page

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use a custom JavaScript macro (in Google Tag Manager) to fetch a item (specifically a pricetag like: € 3,09) from a page. Then alternate it so it will be 3.09 in order for GTM to use it.

So my javascript needs to:

- Fetch the price from the DOM (class rightPrice)
- Strip the € sign and *space* and replace the , with a .

Right now I've scraped this together but I got a feeling this is not even in the right direction:

```
function() {

var txt=document.getElementByClassName("rightPrice").innerHTML;

document.write(txt);

//somehow alter the value

return now.productPrice();
  }
```

Comment: is it working? [document.getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection and [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) receive a string with the markup to write

Answer (score 0):

If you attach a DOM id to the price element, you could potentially configure a DOM Element macro.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a macro and give it a name
2. Set the macro type to 'DOM Element'
3. Set the Element ID to the DOM id that you assigned in the markup; prefix with #, of course
4. Press 'Save'.

This technique is cleaner and requires no custom Javascript.